# check multiple values in an if statement in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to if the value of an input box is blank or not by doing the below:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id').substr(3);
var lengthname = $("#input_name_"+id).val().length;
var lengthrss = $("#input_rss_"+id).val().length;
if (lengthrss!=0 || lengthname!=0)
{
  // do something
}
else
{
alert('Values cannot be blank');
}
```

For some reason it is not doing the OR however if the user enters both values as blanks then the alert comes up??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is an AND operation, not OR. The valid case is when *both* lengths are non-zero:

```
if (lengthrss!=0 && lengthname!=0)
{
  // do something
}
```

Alternatively:

```
if (lengthrss==0 || lengthname==0)
{
  alert('Values cannot be blank');
}
```

For reference: [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: goshh...u r right....I feel dumb...i guess i can't think at 1 a.m. in the morning ;-)

Comment: Yes, trivial mistakes are usually a reminder that it is bed time ;)